# Why doesn't my centos VM use fullscreen on VMPlayer

Tags: centos, vmware-player

I am using VMWare Player 6.0.3 build-1895310 on Windows 7 (host) running CentOS 5.9 as Guest OS. I have always had this sporadic problem, wherein when I start my Guest OS the login screen of CentOS seems to be using fullscreen, but when I login (90% of the time), the desktop is never in full screen and there is nothing I can do to change the resolution.

I also have the latest VMWare tools installed.

```
[root@localhost ~]# vmware-toolbox-cmd -v
9.6.2.31837 (build-1688356)
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I have tried the following things:

- Restarting VMWare Player multiple times, then suspending the VM and restarting the VM
- Reinstalling the VMWare Tools
- Its only with some combinations of the above two steps, that I can see rarely my desktop screen in fullscreen. But 100% of time, the login screen is always in fullscreen.
- When i logout, I again see the full screen login screen

This is how the login screen looks always (fullscreen):
[image]

This is how the desktop screen looks 90% of the time (NOT fullscreen): Please help!!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.
It seems that an xorg.conf magically appeared, only with a display entry in it.
In my case I had to remove the xorg.conf and restart the vm.

Kind regards

Urs